# Move QLabel after show() is called for hidden QWidget

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qlabel

I have a QDialog window where a bar to input text is shown, together with two buttons (one for accept and one for cancel), and the top instruction "Please, provide ID...". At the same time I have a warning/error message which is hidden by default.

The window is something like this:

[image]

The problem is that when I call the `show()` to display the warning, it does not rescale the window, so the warning is shown on top the rest of the input bar. As seen below:

[image]

I have been looking at some properties like `sizePolicy` or even using `adjustSize`, but I have not been able to make for example the top instruction just move a bit to the top when the warning is displayed so they do not stack on top of each other.

I image there should be an easy way of managing this, could someone point out what am I missing or what should I change?

The version of Qt that I am using is Qt 5.4

Comment: Do you use any layout for dialog? Is label in that layout?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements must be in the layout. The warning has not been added to the layout, and thus when it's shown it retains its original position.

For reference, the dialog could be written approximately as follows:

```
class IdDialog : public QDialog {
  QGridLayout m_layout{this};
  QLabel m_header{tr("Enter an ID")};
  QLabel m_warning{tr("<font color=\"red\">Subject not found.</font>")};
  QLineEdit m_subject;
  QDialogButtonBox m_box;
  QPushButton *const m_disconnect = m_box.addButton(tr("Disconnect"), QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole);
  QPushButton *const m_confirm = m_box.addButton(tr("Confirm"), QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole);
public:
  IdDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent) 
  {
    m_layout.addWidget(0, 0, &m_header);
    m_layout.addWidget(1, 0, &m_warning);
    m_layout.addWidget(2, 0, &m_subject);
    m_layout.addWidget(3, 0, &m_box);
    m_warning.hide();
    // connect signals here, etc.
  }
};
```